# Existe alguma ferramenta para auxiliar na otimização do layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, otimização

As vezes é comum a dúvida de qual layout usar, quais recursos gráficos consomem mais memória e como melhorar a disposição em que as view aparecem. Existe alguma ferramenta para auxiliar na otimização do layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe sim, uma maneira é através da View Hierarchy que está incluída nas ferramentas do SDK do Android. Permitindo analisar o layout enquanto o aplicativo está sendo executado. Usando esta ferramenta ajuda você a descobrir os gargalos no desempenho layout, ou seja, ajudando você a identificar possíveis problemas..

```
O hierarchyviewer ferramenta está disponível em <SDK> / tools /
```

Quando aberto, a View Hierarchy mostra uma lista de dispositivos disponíveis e seus componentes em execução.

Link documentação para mais informações e esclarecimentos: [Link Documentação](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html#Inspect)